# Jquery multiple classes not working on mobile browsers - how do I trace the conflicts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm trying to figure out why my navigation menu will not work within mobile browsers.  Ive tried android and chrome mobile and it doesnt work.  Sometimes if I load the page, then navigate to a new page, and come back, the menutoggle works fine, but it does not seem to work:  mshake.honeybadgerofmoney.com  in the upper right corner.  BUT  right click > inspect element then click the mobile phone icon to simulate a mobile browser to see the behavior I'm referencing.

The menu appears on mobile, but it does not navigate to the anchor link as it should.  I've tried to:

change the loading order of the scripts loading in my header tag

```
                                    <a href="#" class="menuToggle scrolly"><span>Menu</span></a>
                                <div id="menu">
                                    <ul>
                <li><a href="#one" class="menuToggle scrolly">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two" class="menuToggle scrolly">Work Samples</a></li>
                <li><a href="#three" class="menuToggle scrolly ">Services We Provide</a></li>
                <li><a href="#message" class="menuToggle scrolly">Contact Us</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

and the JS portion:

```
    <!-- Scripts -->


        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>          
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/contact.js"></script>   


        <!-- Add fancyBox -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

        <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

Any ideas?